# Adding existing project folders to the project explorer in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Probably a very straight forward solution here, but can't seem to find an answer. I recently changed my eclipse workspace to my dropbox folder, so I can work on my netbook when in college and on my desktop when at home. I copied and pasted all my project folders from the old workspace into the dropbox workspace, changed the workspace location in eclipse, but none of the projects are showing up in the project explorer now. Having refreshed the project explorer many times now to no avail, is there any way to add these projects into the project explorer? Thanks

Answer (score 72):

1. From the main menu bar, select **File > Import**. The Import wizard opens.[image]
2. Collapse or click **+** in **General > Existing Project into Workspace** and click **Next**.[image]
3. Choose either **Select root directory** or **Select archive file** and click the associated **Browse** to locate the directory or file containing the projects.[image]
4. Under **Projects** select the project or projects which you would like to import.
   [image]
5. Click **Finish** to start the import.
   [image]

Answer (score 13):

I have had this problem in many versions of Eclipse and followed the process outlined by @vijin-paulraj, but frustratingly kept failing...

Until I noticed that the checkbox at the bottom of the wizard "Copy projects into workspace" is checked by default, and does not have an eventhandler attached to it. So if you do not clear this box **before** selecting the directory it will tell you that "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace." Clearing the checkbox after this will not trigger a form refresh and the Finish button will remain disabled.

[image]

TIP: once the checkbox is cleared, select the directory again will trigger form validation and allow you to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Try importing existing project:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wf/v2r7m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-importproject.htm

Comment: I tried various ways and keep getting " No projects are found to import"

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to make sure that I was in the correct working set.

I was in the working set from training and had not placed my new project into a working set at all.

While the above answers will most likely place your project into Eclipse, a working set will exclude you from seeing any project that is not placed in it from the package explorer.

My personal answer was to create a new working set to keep it separate from work, via the context menu from the upside down triangle at the top left of the package explorer.

Yours may be to modify your current set by adding the new project to it. This option is also located in the same menu.

My circumstance could have been avoided in the "new project" wizard, if I had placed it in a set from there.

I hope this has been useful. Please, feel free to ask for clarification.