# Importing projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This is a copy of the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924229/adding-existing-project-folders-to-the-project-explorer-in-eclipse) post. I have tried the steps suggested in the first(top) answer but when I select the root directory, nothing shows up in the projects column. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a `.project` file in the folder you selected?

Comment: or any folder below it, that is, are there existing (eclipse) projects there?

Comment: @second yes there is a .project file in the selected folder

Comment: What `os` and eclipse version are you using? Maybe its a permission problem?

Comment: @second I'm using windows 10, eclipse 4.12.0. I'm not sure if I see any permission problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of importing using the existing project dialogue, use the "Projects from Folder or Archive" option:

[image]

Then choose your root directory:

[image]

If for some reason your project doesn't import as the type of project you want (for example, it doesn't appear as a Java project even though it is), you'll have to add the required nature to the project.

1. Right click on the project > Properties
2. Choose *Project Natures*
3. Click *Add*
4. Select the desired nature. For this example, I've selected Java
5. *Okay* > *Apply and Close*

[image]